# ComboBox SelectedItem from DataTable Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datatable

I have a method in my DAL which populates a `ComboBox` from a `DataTable`. ComboBox displays correctly and I have a 'Save' button which saves back to my DB, job's a good'un...

```
 public string populateLookUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Combo, string Id)
    {
        SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand();
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        _comm.CommandText = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetName(@id) ORDER BY [name]; ";   
        _comm.Connection = _conn;
        _comm.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = _comm.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(myReader);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to populate Name LookUp");
        }

        Combo.DataSource = dt;            
        Combo.DisplayMember = "name";

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (dr["company_int_name"].ToString() == Contract.Company_trans_Selling_Entity.ToString())
            {
                Combo.SelectedItem = dr["company_int_name"].ToString();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

However obviously when I re-edit the record, this method is called again. Ok, I now have written a `ForEach` loop which iterates over my DataTable and compares the string in the rows to the Name I am passing in. If the two match I'm setting the

```
Combo.SeletedItem =  dr["company_int_name"].ToString();
```

However the `selectedItem` is not being set, presumably I'll need some sort of event to notify the property changed?

Thanks

Comment: when you save the record, do you store the selected value from the combobox?

Comment: Yeah I have a save method which is passed the value. This value is passed into a sql INSERT statement.

Comment: Try using the text property of the Combobox, something like this: `Combo.Text = Contract.Name.ToString();` instead of using the `SelectedItem` property

Comment: just a suggestion .
you can  unregistering the selectedIndexChanged eventhandler ( if u have one) at the start of the method and then reregistering it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the Combo Box with the ValueMember function and can reflect the combo box  with the matched string value as selected

```
public string populateLookUp(ref System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Combo, string Id)
{
    SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand();
    _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
    _comm.CommandText = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetName(@id) ORDER BY [name]; ";   
    _comm.Connection = _conn;
    _comm.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader myReader = _comm.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(myReader);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to populate Name LookUp");
    }

    Combo.DataSource = dt;            
    Combo.DisplayMember = "name";
    Combo.ValueMember = "name";

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["company_int_name"].ToString() == Contract.Company_trans_Selling_Entity.ToString())
        {
            Combo.SelectedValue = dr["company_int_name"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```